# The Bridge chatroom is struggling with reopening after the browser has been closed

Tags: bug, chat

In [The Bridge chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), me and a number of other users have the problem that when we close our browser (for me it's Edge 101) and reopen it (for example, when rebooting our computers or signing out of Windows), the chatroom doesn't load properly. It keeps hanging on the splash modal that should automatically go away, but it does not.

I don't have this issue on other chatrooms: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64176/this-is-fine loads just fine within seconds.

The weird part is that problem goes away temporarily when doing a control-R refresh from inside the Edge dev tools network tab, and I think I also managed to make it go away temporarily when closing the tab, closing the browser and then reopening it, but neither of these solutions are permanent.

Comment: I've reproduced this issue even just from joining the chat room from the link from this post. Something weird is going on. It took around 30 seconds at a standstill to fully open.

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome 101, South-East Asia. Looks like sometimes [it fails to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q61F.png) the URL https://chat.stackexchange.com/chats/35/events until canceled and got stuck.

Comment: (note that the content of that API is like, the 100 recent chat messages)

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Just FYI: The response from that endpoint can be up to 500 chat messages from any point in the room's transcript, depending on the request. The parameters used in the POST when a chat room is opened result in returning the most recent 100 chat messages for that room, which are then used for what is displayed.

Comment: Given the notable number of oneboxed content in the currently most recent 100 messages, I'd hypothesize that those have something to do with it, but it's unclear why that would be an issue on the backend which would cause the request for the messages to fail and/or take an extended period of time. Based on oneboxed content, at least from SE posts, comments, chat messages, continuing to be available in the transcript when the source is deleted, I would have assumed that what's stored in the chat database is the rendered HTML for the chat message, not the Markdown.

Comment: @Makyen yeah, I tried calling `$.post('https://chat.stackexchange.com/chats/35/events', { since:0, msgCount:99, mode:'Messages', fkey:fkey().fkey}, function() {}, 'json' );` with smaller counts and that worked. Until I tried 100 and then it failed. only 15K in the response payload so that doesn't seem too much. Not a clue what triggers this.

Comment: Yeah, it's an endpoint that's used all the time by chat (e.g. every time you open a chat room). It's also used by multiple userscripts, generally without problems. It's a highly used endpoint. The SOCVR Archiver we use routinely calls that endpoint to request 500 messages at a time, for a few thousand messages, many times a day. It's strange that the intermittent failure is common for that room. I do have times when I see something similar in other rooms, but that's usually when my browser is starting up and opening many tabs, so I've assumed my issues were concurrency related in my browser.

Comment: @Makyen There aren't actually that many oneboxed messages in the current chatroom. A couple years ago we had a bot that would post a oneboxed message for every question posted on the site (we since dialed it back to only hot questions) and during low traffic moments it could happen that entire pages were like 3 normal messages and then 47 oneboxed messages without issues.

Comment: My best guess is it's some now-deleted chat message that cause problems.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar That would be weird considering that AFAICT there are no deleted messages among those 100 posts. However, there ARE 35 "some time later" messages. Maybe it's related to that?

Comment: @Nzall the "[x] hours/days later" is normal, it's when there is gap between messages, just checked Tavern and it's the same. So not the cause either, I'm afraid. Next suspect, the feeds, maybe something there get stuck when loading them. But we can't really know, only developer digging into this have real chance to find the actual cause and fix it.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar the strange part is that the network connection gets dropped. So there is not even an 500 error being returned, you simply never get an ACK down in layer 3 or 4 in the ISO model on a sent network packet.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar Nope, there are no deleted chat messages in the most recent couple hundred messages in that room. That's something which you should be able to determine for yourself, as there will be a "(deleted)" message shown in the actual chat room for any deleted messages. OTOH, there could be something in the database which doesn't make it into the page, in either the chat room or transcripts, but it's definitely not a "normal" deleted chat message.

Comment: @rene yeah, well such things do happen to me sometimes when the request get "stuck" due to the server simply not returning any response. (In my own code.)

Comment: The same issue seems to be happening with https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room